# Conjectural improvement of Cauchy-Schwarz inequality for integrals

Tags: definite-integrals, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

The following conjecture is a possible improvement of the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.

**Conjecture:** Let $f,g$ be two continuous, integrable, positive functions on $[a,b]$, where $a,b\in[0,1]$. Then
$$\int_{a}^{b}f^{2}\left(x\right)dx\int_{a}^{b}g^{2}\left(x\right)dx-\left(\int_{a}^{b}f\left(x\right)g\left(x\right)dx\right)^{2}\left(1+\min_{x\in\left[a,b\right]}\left(f\left(x\right)g\left(x\right)\right)^{2}\right)\geq 0,$$
provided that
$$\int_{a}^{b}f^{2}\left(x\right)dx\int_{a}^{b}g^{2}\left(x\right)dx-\left(\int_{a}^{b}f\left(x\right)g\left(x\right)dx\right)^{2}-\min_{x\in\left[a,b\right]}\left(f\left(x\right)g\left(x\right)\right)\geq 0$$ and $$\min_{x\in\left[a,b\right]}f(x)g(x)<1.$$

There are several proofs of the classical Cauchy-Schwarz inequality. Unfortunately I cannot find a proof, counterexample or reference for my conjecture.

Here are two functions which satisfy the two inequalities :

$$f\left(x\right)=e^{x}-0.999,g\left(x\right)=e^{x}-0.98,a=0,b=1/2$$

$$f\left(x\right)=x^{-1}e^{\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)}+0.001,g\left(x\right)=e^{-\frac{\cos\left(x\right)}{x}}+0.5,a=0.11,b=1$$

For a related reference see: [*On some integral inequalities related to the Cauchy–Bunyakovsky–Schwarz inequality*](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0893965910001424)
by N.S. Barnett, S.S. Dragomir and I. Gomm.

Update 1:

As nobody find a counter-example a proof might be likely.

I think the best way to tackle it is the proof by contradiction but I don't know how to start even if I was thinking of probability and inequality like Markov's inequality .

To dig a counter-example :

Using extreme-value theorem for integral we have where $m\le g(x),m'\leq f(x)$ :

$$m'\int_{a}^{b}f\left(x\right)dx\leq\int_{a}^{b}f\left(x\right)g\left(x\right)dx,m\int_{a}^{b}g\left(x\right)dx\leq\int_{a}^{b}f\left(x\right)g\left(x\right)dx$$

So with the condition we have :

$$\int_{a}^{b}f^{2}\left(x\right)dx\int_{a}^{b}g^{2}\left(x\right)dx-\left(m\int_{a}^{b}g\left(x\right)dx\right)^{2}\cdot\left(m'\int_{a}^{b}f\left(x\right)dx\right)^{2}-\min_{x\in\left[a,b\right]}f(x)g(x)\geq 0$$

Or again using extreme-value theorem :

$$\int_{a}^{b}f^{2}\left(x\right)dx\int_{a}^{b}g^{2}\left(x\right)dx-\left(mm'\int_{a}^{b}g^2\left(x\right)dx\right)^{2}\cdot\left(mm'\int_{a}^{b}f^2\left(x\right)dx\right)^{2}-\min_{x\in\left[a,b\right]}f(x)g(x)\geq 0$$

So solving the quadratic we get a lower bound for $$\int_{a}^{b}f^{2}\left(x\right)dx\int_{a}^{b}g^{2}\left(x\right)dx$$

Question: How to prove/disprove my conjecture?

Comment: Is it intentional that you have a *factor* $\left(1+\min_{x\in\left[a,b\right]}\left(f\left(x\right)g\left(x\right)\right)^{2}\right)$ in the first line, but an *additive* term $ \min_{x\in\left[a,b\right]}\left(f\left(x\right)g\left(x\right)\right)^{2}$ in the second line?

Comment: @MartinR For logical reason it ensure the equality case

Comment: It would be helpful if you explain *why* you think this is true, and *why* the second condition is formulated as it is.

Comment: Also some examples of functions satisfying the given condition would be nice.

Comment: If $f$ and $g$ satisfy the second inequality (and the minimum is not zero) then $Cf$ and $Cg$ with a positive real constant $C$ also satisfy the second inequality. But $Cf$ and $Cg$ cannot satisfy the first inequality for arbitrarily large $C$.

Comment: @MartinR I misreading my paper see my edits .Have you a counter-example now ? If yes it would be very nice !

Comment: I have no idea whether the conjecture is true, but it is a misnomer to call it an "improvement" on Cauchy-Schwarz, because you've added conditions that are generally impossible to check without knowing the values of the integrals you're trying to get an inequality for.  The usefulness of Cauchy-Schwarz is in its non-circularity.

Comment: @JohnDoe Perhaps there is some hope even  it seems impossible .

Comment: Have you read Martin's comment above?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez be explicit please .

Comment: Proving inequalities by contradiction is, while technically possible, not the most often trodden path...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The conjecture is not true. Here is a counterexample.

Consider $a=0$, $b=1$, $f(x)=2x+\frac12$ and $g(x)=6x+\frac12$.

$\int_0^1f^{2}(x)dx=\frac {31}{12}.$
$\int_0^1g^{2}(x)dx=\frac{61}{4}.$
$\int_0^1f(x)g(x)dx=\frac{25}{4}.$
$\min_{x\in [0,1]}f(x)g(x)=\frac14.$
$\int_0^1f^{2}(x)dx\int_0^1g^{2}(x)dx-(\int_0^1f(x)g(x)dx)^2-\min_{x\in [0,1]}f(x)g(x)=\frac{1}{12}>0$
$\int_0^1f^{2}(x)dx\int_0^1g^{2}(x)dx-(\int_0^1f(x)g(x)dx)^2(1+\min_{x\in [0,1]}(f(x)g(x))^2)=\frac{-1619}{768}<0.$

Comment: Give a counter-example with values not a sketch which fails please .

Comment: Here is another counterexample. $a=0$, $b=1$, $f(x)=\frac12$ and $g(x)=5x+1$.

Comment: Nice thanks you !

Comment: You are welcome!