# Conjecture improvement of Bunyakovsky integral inequality $\int_{0}^{I}g(t)dt\leq J$

Tags: definite-integrals, examples-counterexamples, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, conjectures

It's a follow-up of my previous question answered by user Apass.Jack nicely. See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4701003/conjectural-improvement-of-cauchy-schwarz-inequality-for-integrals) for motivation and background.

Conjecture :

> Let $f$ be a positive increasing continuous function on $x\in[0,1]$ and $g$ be an integrable  decreasing positive continuous function on $x\in(0,\infty)$. Let
> $$J=\left(\int_{0}^{1}\left(f\left(x\right)\right)^{2}dx\int_{0}^{1}\left(g\left(x\right)\right)^{2}dx-\left(\int_{0}^{1}f\left(x\right)g\left(x\right)dx\right)^{2}\right)\max_{x\in\left[0,1\right]}\left(g\left(x\right)\right)$$
> and $$I=\left(\int_{0}^{1}\left(f\left(x\right)\right)^{2}dx\int_{0}^{1}\left(g\left(x\right)\right)^{2}dx-\left(\int_{0}^{1}f\left(x\right)g\left(x\right)dx\right)^{2}\right).$$
> Then
> $$\left(\int_{0}^{I}g\left(t\right)dt\right)\leq J.$$

Now the usual counterexample doesn't works @Apass.jack.

Here is one example :

Choosing $g(x)=\arccos(x),f(x)=\arcsin(x)$ we have :

$$2\frac{\left(1/4(2(2+((1+\pi)(4-(\pi-3)\pi^{2}))^{\frac{1}{2}})+\pi((\pi-3)\pi\arccos(1/4(\pi-3)\pi^{2})-((1+\pi)(4-(\pi-3)\pi^{2}))^{\frac{1}{2}}))\right)}{\pi}< \left(\frac{1}{4}\left(\pi^{2}-8\right)\left(\pi-2\right)-\left(2-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^{2}\right)$$

$$I=\int_{0}^{1}e^{-x^{2}}dx\int_{0}^{1}\left(1+\frac{1}{2}e^{-x}\right)dx-\left(\int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{e^{-x^{2}}\left(1+\frac{1}{2}e^{-x}\right)}dx\right)^{2},$$
$$\left|\int_{0}^{I}e^{-t^{2}}dt-I\right|<6\cdot10^{-7}$$

As I have no idea for a proof, here is my question.

How to (dis)prove my conjecture?

Comment: @MartinR OK .Can you make an answer ?

Comment: I have already voted to close the question because I do not think that it is a good question for this site. As @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez said, it is a random conjecture without any motivation or background. Sorry if that sounds rude, but I would suggest to delete the question. I do not see that future readers will benefit from the question or an answer.

Comment: It would be nice if, in future, you linked to your "previous question".

Comment: @user1729 See my edits .

Comment: @Apass.Jack Have you something or a counter-example ?

Comment: Martin R's comment from May 22 already answered your conjecture positively, but while it is true it is not any stronger than Cauchy-Schwarz, in fact the monotonicity conditions are not necessary.

Comment: @BrunoB No see $$I=\left(\int_{0}^{1}\left(f\left(x\right)\right)^{2}dx\int_{0}^{1}\left(g\left(x\right)\right)^{2}dx-\left(\int_{0}^{1}f\left(x\right)g\left(x\right)dx\right)^{2}\right),g\left(x\right)=50x,f\left(x\right)=\frac{1}{x+1},\frac{\left(\int_{0}^{I}g\left(t\right)dt\right)}{g\left(1\right)}>I$$

Comment: Ah I see. $g$ being decreasing is necessary because you chose $\max_{[0,1]} g$, my bad, but otherwise $f$'s increasingness is not needed. Since $g$ is decreasing, its supremum overall is equal to its supremum on $[0,1]$ (since it's equal to $\lim_{x \to 0^+} g(x)$) and as such what Martin R said is still true. Note that the supremum might not be a maximum due to how you defined $g$ but that's not really an issue.

Comment: @BrunoB I don't think so .If you have a proof please show us !

Comment: @ErikSatie: $I \ge 0$ is the CS inequality. Also $g$ is positive and decreasing, so that $$\int_0^I g(t) dt \le  I \cdot \max_{x \in [0, I]} g(x) = I \cdot \max_{x \in [0, 1]} g(x) = J$$

Comment: @MartinR How you extract $I$ from the integral to the other side? it's very magical...

Comment: @ErikSatie: The integral is $\le $ the length of the interval (which is $I$), multiplied with the maximum of the integrand.

Comment: @MartinR As young integral inequality ?

Comment: @MartinR OK .(+1) for you .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\max_{x \in [0, I]} g(x) \le\max_{x\in[0,\infty)}g(x)=\max_{x\in[0,1]}g(x)$$
where the last equality holds because $g(x)$ is decreasing on $[1,\infty)$.

Bunyakovsky integral inequality  says $I\ge0$. As Martin R observed,

$$\int_0^I g(t)\,\text{d}t \le\int_0^I\max_{x \in [0, I]} g(x)\,\text{d}t =  I \cdot \max_{x \in [0, I]} g(x) \le I \cdot \max_{x \in [0, 1]} g(x) = J.$$